# ibatis cache miss when i reconnect page on java spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, mybatis, ibatis

as long as cached data isn't cleared, I want to use Cached DB data when table is even truncated and empty.

I set cachemodel on my spring application which using iBatis.
I wonder why I got 'cache miss' log when I reconnect controller.
Cache worked on same session when I repeat request of same query. 
but when I reconnect page,
I got 'cache miss' log and cache was stored.
please check my code and advise me what is solution for this problem. or is it correct result?

**sqlmap-bnkmst.xml**

```
<sqlMap namespace="bnkMst"> 
<cacheModel id="bnkMstCache" type="LRU" readOnly="true" serialize="false">
    <flushInterval hours="24"/>
    <property name="reference-type" value="STRONG" />        
    <property name="cache-size" value="1000" /> 
</cacheModel>

<resultMap id="bnkMstResMap" class="com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dto.bnkMstTEO">
    <result property="id" column="bnk_no" />
    <result property="knNm" column="bnk_nm_kn" />
    <result property="enNm" column="bnk_nm_en" />
    <result property="cd" column="bnk_cd" />
</resultMap>

<select id="selectAllBnkMst" resultMap="bnkMstResMap" cacheModel="bnkMstCache">
      SELECT * FROM BNK_MST
</select>
<select id="getBnkMstById" parameterClass="java.lang.Integer" resultMap="bnkMstResMap" cacheModel="bnkMstCache">
      SELECT * FROM BNK_MST WHERE BNK_NO = #value#
</select>
......omitted
......omitted
</sqlMap>
```

**ibatisController.java**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.controller;

......omitted

@Controller
public class ibatisController {

    @RequestMapping("/ibatis")
    public ModelAndView showMessage(
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) int id) throws SQLException, IOException {
        bnkMstDAO manager = new bnkMstDAOImpl();

        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("sql-maps-config.xml");
        SqlMapClient sqlmapClient = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient (reader);     

        bnkMstTEO bean = manager.getBnkMstById(id, sqlmapClient); //1st

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("ibatisTest");
        mv.addObject("knNm", bean.getKnNm());
        mv.addObject("enNm", bean.getEnNm());

        bean = manager.getBnkMstById(id, sqlmapClient); //2nd
//......omitted
        bean = manager.getBnkMstById(id, sqlmapClient); //3rd
//......omitted


        return mv;
    }
}
```

**bnkMstDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dto.bnkMstTEO;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient;

public class bnkMstDAOImpl implements bnkMstDAO
{

    public bnkMstTEO getBnkMstById(Integer id, SqlMapClient sqlmapClient) {
        try
        {
            bnkMstTEO teo = (bnkMstTEO)sqlmapClient.queryForObject("bnkMst.getBnkMstById", id);
            return teo;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return null;
    }
    public List selectAllBnkMst(SqlMapClient sqlmapClient) throws SQLException{
        List list = sqlmapClient.queryForList("bnkMst.selectAllBnkMst");
        return list;
    }

    public void delBnkMstById(Integer id, SqlMapClient sqlmapClient) {
        try
        {
            sqlmapClient.delete("bnkMst.deleteBnkMstById", id);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

this is Log when I launched

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - Cache 'bnkMst.bnkMstCache': cache miss
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - Created connection 411106513.
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {conn-100012} Connection
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {conn-100012} Preparing Statement:      SELECT * FROM BNK_MST WHERE BNK_NO = ?  
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {pstm-100013} Executing Statement:      SELECT * FROM BNK_MST WHERE BNK_NO = ?  
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {pstm-100013} Parameters: [1]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {pstm-100013} Types: [java.lang.Integer]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {rset-100014} ResultSet
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {rset-100014} Header: [bnk_no, bnk_nm_kn, bnk_nm_en, bnk_cd]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - {rset-100014} Result: [1, bank1, bank1, 0001]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - Cache 'bnkMst.bnkMstCache': stored object 'com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dto.bnkMstTEO@484f7153'
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - Returned connection 411106513 to pool.
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - Cache 'bnkMst.bnkMstCache': retrieved object 'com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dto.bnkMstTEO@484f7153'
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-8] - Cache 'bnkMst.bnkMstCache': retrieved object 'com.howtodoinjava.ibatis.demo.dto.bnkMstTEO@484f7153'
```

Comment: Look into MyBatis.  It has a mybatis-spring extension, is a newer version of IBatis, and will handle the SqlMapClient for you (with spring configuration).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create `SqlMapClient` on every request. Cache is managed in `SqlMapClient` so when it is destroyed (at end of the HTTP request in your case) cache content is lost.

The recommended way to use `SqlMapClient` is to have it configured as singleton in your application.